# Different Views for same domain Object in Grails backend and frontend

Tags: grails, plugins, view, local, gsp

I've got two grails projects (admin backend and frontend) using the same domain classes from a local plugin.

I need to have different views in the frontend and the backend. E.g. there's a domain class Event. In each of the projects I use GenerateViews. Then I modify the generated gsps. As an example take the list.gsp. In frontend I remove the actions to create a new event from the view and the Controller, in the backend I keep them. That's because in the frontend the users should be only able to see the list of events, while in the backend the admin creates and modifies what is displayed in the frontend. This is the structure I get:

project domain

- domain/grails-app/domain/myapp/Event.groovy

project frontend (grails.plugin.location.'domain' = "../domain")

- frontend/grails-app/controllers/myapp/frontend/EventController.groovy
- frontend/grails-app/views/event/list.gsp (no links to edit / create action)

project backend (grails.plugin.location.'domain' = "../domain")

- backend/grails-app/controllers/myapp/backend/EventController.groovy
- backend/grails-app/views/event/list.gsp (links to edit/create...)

But when I run my frontend application using run-app, and go to list, the controller is called:

```
def listEvents(Integer max) {

    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [eventInstanceList: Event.list(params), eventInstanceTotal: Event.count()]

}
```

and as a result backend/grails-app/views/event/list.gsp is rendered instead of frontend/grails-app/views/event/list.gsp.

The confusion already begins when I'm generating the views. So when I generate views for domain/grails-app/domain/myapp/Event.groovy inside the backend project everything is fine. The views get created inside my backend projectand work as intended.

Then I move ober to the frontend project and generate views for domain/grails-app/domain/myapp/Event.groovy. This time grails will tell me that there already are views, and asks if I want to replace them. If I say yes, it doesn't replace anything, but create the views in my frontend project. Really weird.

I found that there is an older bug report related to this, and I created a new one (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9920).

In the meantime, what should I do to work around this? I could rename my controllers' methods and the views, but I hope that there's a better way. It seems odd, that a view by the same name may override a view in a separate project. Or does something like that only happen when using run-app?

I'm new to Grails, so maybe I missed something obvious, but this really scares me, since it looks like I might accidentally expose actions in one project by modifying the other.

Comment: Your setup isn't entirely clear to me, but I have one initial thought: take a look at the `plugin` parameter supported by `render()`: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry if my problem description isn't clear enough. Thanks for the hint. My problem is, that even if I'm running only one of the two projetcs, e.g. frontend, and I've got a view defined in this project this view is not used. Instead the view from project backend is used. I do not even have backend defined as a dependency in frontend.